The difference between Khovanov homology and Jones Polynomial for knots
I just learned some Khovanov Homology, and do not understand it deep enough.
It is clear that Khovanov homology is stronger than Jones polynomial in link theory because Jones polynomial cannot distinguish unlink but Khovanov Homology can.
However, are there any advantages for Khovanov Homology rather than Jones Polynomial for knots?
I know Khovanov Homology can detect unknot, but it does not mean Jones Polynomial cannot (though not proved yet).
So my question is, is Jones Polynomial equivalent to Khovanov Homology as an invariant for knots? (i.e. they have the same abilities to distinguish knots)
Thanks!

This is not a question anyone can currently answer; if they were proven equivalent, we would know that the Jones Polynomial could detect the unknot precisely because Khovanov homology does.

Okay, it is impossible that they two are equivalent. On Dror Bar-Natan's paper, page 357, $J(5_1)=J(10_{132})$, but for Khovanov Homology, they are not.
